# Match always succeeds when dereferencing pointer OCaml

Tags: ocaml

My code is the following

```
let newObj (s) : someObj = 
   let myStr = ref s in
   let myInt = ref 0 in {
       someFun = (fun newS ->
           match !myStr with
           | newS -> true
           | _ -> false
   }
;;
```

I have tested this code

```
let test = newObj "right";;
test.someFun "right";;
test.someFun "wrong";;
```

Both calls to someFun return true.

I have also tried

```
if (!mystr = newS) then true else false
```

and this works. Why?

Comment: Can you precise what exactly is your problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The meaning of an identifier in a pattern is not what you seem to think. Any identifier that appears in a pattern is a *new* occurrence of the id that will be bound to whatever value is matched. So, this match:

```
       match !myStr with
       | newS -> true
       | _ -> false
```

will always match on the first case. It binds the identifier `newS` to the value `!myStr`; however this has no visible effect since you don't use `newS` in the associated expression.

The `newS` in the pattern has nothing to do with any previous appearance of the identifier `newS`. This is a *new* use of the identifier.

That's why the `if` statement works. It is referring to the existing binding of the identifier (there's no pattern involved).

As I side comment, when I enter the expression above, the compiler warns me as follows:

```
Warning 11: this match case is unused.
```

The compiler is pointing out that the second branch of the match will never be used. The first branch always matches.

It's good to pay attention to warnings like this.